# TemplateDoesNotExist at / base.html

Tags: python, django

friends.
I try to repeat by doing the example of project in book: "Learning Django Web Development" by Jaiswal, Sanjeev.

Running the server i get such exception: TemplateDoesNotExist at /base.html

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
base.html

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.8.3
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    base.html

Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 46
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.EXE
Python Version:     3.4.3
Python Path:    

['C:\\dj\\mytweets',
'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python34.zip',
'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python34\\lib',
'C:\\Python34',
'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Tue, 14 Jul 2015 14:01:27 +0300
```

Template-loader postmortem

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

    Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
    Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
        C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\base.html (File does not exist)
        C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\base.html (File does not exist)
```

My settings.py file:

```
import os

SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, os.pardir)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH)
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "templates")

SECRET_KEY = 'khcr3h6u+ghi+rtb+g_(mvgq!mtn9u4&%=hu20vt2*u(p8-kde'

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tweets',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mytweets.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mytweets.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__),
        'static',
    ),
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

I tried to change settings.py in such way too:

changed settings.py:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")

SECRET_KEY = 'khcr3h6u+ghi+rtb+g_(mvgq!mtn9u4&%=hu20vt2*u(p8-kde'

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tweets',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mytweets.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mytweets.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__),
        'static',
    ),
)
```

My project structure:

[image: My project structure:]

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render


class Index(View):
    def get(self, request):
        params = {}
        params['name'] = 'Django'
        return render(request, 'base.html', params)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from tweets.views import Index
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Traceback:

```
Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\base.html    (File does not exist)
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\base.html (File does not exist)



Traceback:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response  
132.response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view  
71.return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch  
89.return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\dj\mytweets\tweets\views.py" in get  
9.return render(request, 'base.html', params)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
67.template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string 
98.template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in get_template  
46.raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: base.html
```

Please, give an advice, what should i change to get rendered page?

Comment: Can you please also share mytweets/urls.py and tweets/views.py.

Comment: Yes, sure. Give a sec

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the book you are using, so I can't give you any advice based on that. If the book is for Django 1.7, you will find it easier to use Django 1.7 instead of Django 1.8, at least when you are beginning with Django.

If you want to stick with Django 1.8, here's how to fix the error you are currently seeing:

Your `settings.py` file has a mixture of old templates settings, like `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` (Django <= 1.7), and the new settings under `TEMPLATES` (Django 1.8+).

First, remove the old settings `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`.

Secondly, it looks as if `DIRS` is incorrect in your `TEMPLATES` setting.

Define `BASE_DIR`, which should be included in `settings.py` by default when you run `./manage.py startproject`

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Then change `TEMPLATES` to

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanx for tip. I changed all the settings you adviced, but it doesn't help

Comment: What does it display when you add print(TEMPLATES) to your `settings.py`? Please [edit] your question and include the new traceback. Copy and paste the text instead of including a screenshot.

Comment: print(TEMPLATES) displays such list:[{'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug', 'django.template.context_processors.request', 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}, 'APP_DIRS': True, 'DIRS': ['C:\\Documents and Settings\\Admin\\Мои документы\\dj\\mytweets\\templates'], 'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates'}]

Comment: And what about the traceback now that you have changed the settings?

Comment: i added the traceback in question's post

Comment: and yes, you are right,  the author uses Django 1.7x in examples.

Comment: Have you restarted the server after making the changes to the settings? I would expect to see an entry underneath `Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:` in the traceback, but it is empty. I don't have any other suggestions, hope you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: tnx, man, all works, after reloading server and saving changes in settings.py. I found an error in my msgi.py file of project...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83205/discussion-between-ufo-and-alasdair).

Comment: I'm using Django 4.0.5, and in ***settings.py*** at TEMPLATES, add this `'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],`, if your templates folder in the project is named templates.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem first I tried to solve it with adding path to shortcuts of HTML templates `{% extends "base.html" %}` to `{% extends "foldername/template/base.html" %}` it did not work.

After that I add to 'base.html' file in every projects templates folder. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In installed apps add mytweets instead of tweets .

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly that problem, base.html not found in my_project/templates/base.html.

I fixed it moving the directory templates just after the app that calls it
(before buggy)

```
--my_project
 --templates
 --app_a
(after fixed)
--my_project
 --app_a
 --templates
```

Answer (score -4):

Set your template path in DIR [] of settings.py

```
 TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [**'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\contrib\\admin\\templates\\admin'**],
        'APP_DIRS':True,
        'OPTIONS': {
```

Comment: never do hardcoded paths in the settings - that code above has 2 major issues - not only it is hardcoded + so many people does not even have C drive, not to mention deploying it into production won't ever work - but anyway hardcoding paths are against proper software engineering and coding conventions...