# django template sensitive with upper or lower case file folder names

Tags: python, django

on *Ubuntu 18*, with Django 2.1.2, I clone a repo from this [github](https://github.com/ShakalakaB/Python_journey_code/tree/back_up-user_accounts_completed/learning_log): 
there is a very odd thing, in learning_logs/templates/,I have to create "Learning_log" for index.html, and "learning_logs" for other html, if i just use one to put all files, it comes TemplateDoesNotExist. detail as following:

just using  "learning_logs":

> "TemplateDoesNotExist" error(TemplateDoesNotExist at /
>   Learning_logs/index.html)

just using "Learnning_logs":

> "TemplateDoesNotExist" error(TemplateDoesNotExist at
>   /learning_logs/base.html)

Seems like it needs "**learning_logs**“ ”Learning_logs" at the same time,

How can I solve it?

Thanks!!

Comment: File paths are case sensitive on Linux - you should consider using consistent case everywhere. The repo you link to has two directories with different case, which is a recipe for confusion.

Comment: the time i ask the question there just one directory: "learning_log", i have to create a two directories to solve this problem, but i just don't know what cause this: i have to create two directory with uppr and lower for templates

Comment: The views in the repo you linked to refer inconsistently to `learning_logs` and `Learning_logs` when rendering templates, which is problematic. You need to pick a case (lowercase is recommended) and use it everywhere.

Comment: the odd thing is if i pick a case, then the error i mention shows, i use these two filenames to solve the problem, but don't understand what cause the problem

Comment: What is your django version?

Comment: django 2.1.2 ...

Comment: That is because your **view** is trying to use both variations. You need to fix the view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TemplateDoesNotExist at / base.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404136/templatedoesnotexist-at-base-html)

Comment: Yes, you are right the error rises when the view cannot find the template but solution is not there.

Comment: you are right, it turn out to be my fault in views.py, thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

This is because in the setting it is not mentioned where to look when a template is called.

Add this in settings under Templates tag or modify for your own purpose:

```
    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),'./learning_logs/templates','./Learning_logs/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
    },
    ]
```

**NOTE:** If the templates folder is in the same directory with settings then adding `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),]'` will be sufficient otherwise location of the folder should be added such as ,`,'./Learning_logs/templates'`

Also, take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/overriding-templates/).

In your view try to remove *learning_logs/* this relatively in all:
Like this:

```
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OP's issue. The issue is case-sensitivity of their template names, not that the templates cannot be found at all.

Comment: it didn't work, and do as above, and put all html file in "learning_log", "TemplateDoesNotExist at /Learning_logs/index.html" comes again

Comment: What is your django version?

Comment: django version-2.1.2

Comment: Have you tried shutting down the server and running again after making my suggestions?

Comment: This is the issue same with yours and it is fixed with a suggestion close to mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404136/templatedoesnotexist-at-base-html

Comment: yeah, i did as you said, and just using "learning_logs" in templates, the "templatesdosenotexist"  keep showing

Comment: I dont understand I am the only one who tries to help and someone comes and just downvotes it.

Comment: @ Rarblack   thanks so much for your help, just as you mentioned, it's the problem with views.py. i appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome! Did you try the last one? By the way can you post your view.py?

Comment: it's in the github link, just in learning_logs/views.py, i will update the change i made soon